# VBA Excel - Extract each value surrounded by brackets

Tags: excel, vba, extract

I want to extract the values surrounded by brackets.

text = "The man who {said} and also {var2} as well as {var3}

```
openingParen = InStr(text, "{")
closingParen = InStr(text, "}")
enclosedValue = Mid(text, openingParen + 1, closingParen - openingParen - 1)

phrasevariable1.Value = enclosedValue
phrasevariable2.Value = enclosedValue
phrasevariable3.Value = enclosedValue
```

This code only works for extracting the first value, is there a way to extract each of the variables, and put them into the textbox 1 -> n accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for an unknown number of candidate tokens;

```
Dim matches As Object
Dim Re As Object: Set Re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim count As Long

Re.Pattern = "{(.*?)}"
Re.Global = True
Set matches = Re.Execute("The man who {said} and also {var2} as well as {var3}")

count = matches.count
For i = 0 To count - 1
    MsgBox matches(i).submatches(0)
Next
```

(Add a ref to *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions* for early binding)

Comment: When I tried this it only returned one match. Is it the `Global = true` that allows it to return multiple matches?

Comment: Yep, if I copy & paste that I see 3 message boxes

Comment: I have a similar scenario, except the strings I have to deal with are bracketed with `]` and `{`.  I'm fairly new to regexp - after a lot of reading, I can get some searches to work, but I can't seem to find the right syntax for these 2 delimiters.

Comment: Square brackets must be escaped as they have significance as a regex character so try `"\[(.*?)\]"`

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Notice my closing delimiter is a `{`, not and not a `]`.  I tried using your example, but not getting quite the results I want.  String to search is `[69] The red-tailed [Hawk]c1{hawk} is a an interesting desert [brd]s1{bird}.` and the pattern is `\](.*?)\{`.  The returned strings are `The red-tailed [Hawk]c1` and `s1`, so something is wrong with the first extraction.

Comment: What do you want to extract from that string?

Comment: The text between `]` and `{`, so in this example that would be `c1` and `s1`

Comment: Try `"]([^\]]*?){"` - i.e. match from a ] where there is not a following  ] to prevent the [69] causing probs

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's perfect!!  I can see I need more practice with this.

Answer (score 3):

Another way allowing for any number of matches:

```
Const stri As String = "The man who {said} and also {var2} as well as {var3}"
Dim sp

sp = Filter(Split(Replace(Chr(13) & stri, "}", "{" & Chr(13)), "{"), Chr(13), False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have three pairs of text in brackets, just create an array variable, and use `split` on your text string to get the values:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Split(text, "{")

phasevariable1.Value  = Left(myArray(1), InStr(myArray(1), "}") - 1)
phasevariable2.Value  = Left(myArray(2), InStr(myArray(2), "}") - 1)
phasevariable3.Value  = Left(myArray(3), InStr(myArray(3), "}") - 1)
```